# Объединить два массива с объединением полей объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите плиз как объединить несколько массивов в один.
Допустим у меня есть массивы следующего вида

```
var first = [
    { id: 1, name: 'first' },
    { id: 2, name: 'second' },
    { id: 3, name: 'third' }
]

var second = [
    { id: 2, filed: 'foo2' },
    { id: 3, field: 'foo3' },
    { id: 4, field: 'foo4' }
]

var third = [
    { id: 2, data: 'some2' },
    { id: 4, data: 'some4' },
    { id: 6, data: 'some6' }
]
```

Я хотел бы объединить их чтобы получить такой результат:

```
var result = [
    { id: 1, name: 'first',   field: undefined, data: undefined },
    { id: 2, name: 'second',  field: 'foo2',    data: 'some2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'third',   field: 'foo3',    data: undefined },
    { id: 4, name: undefined, field: 'foo4',    data: 'some4' },
    { id: 5, name: undefined, field: undefined, data: undefined },
    { id: 6, name: undefined, field: undefined, data: 'some6' }
]
```

Как это можно сделать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

```js
function merge(){
  var result = [];
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function(arr){ // Проходимся по переданным агрументам, функция принимает неограниченное количество аргументов
    if(Array.isArray(arr)){
      for(e in arr){ // Проходимся по всем
        e = arr[e];  // переданным объектам
        var tmp = {}, isAdd = true;
      
        result.some(function(i){
          if(i.id == e.id){
            tmp = i;       // Если в массиве уже был объект с данным id, то берём его
            isAdd = false; // и запрещаем добавлять его в результат
            return true;
          }
        });
      
        for(prop in e){
          tmp[prop] = e[prop]; // Изменяем/добавляем свойства из переданного объекта
        }
      
        if(isAdd)
          result.push(tmp);
      }
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}


var first = [
    { id: 1, name: 'first' },
    { id: 2, name: 'second' },
    { id: 3, name: 'third' }
];

var second = [
    { id: 2, filed: 'foo2' },
    { id: 3, field: 'foo3' },
    { id: 4, field: 'foo4' }
];

var third = [
    { id: 2, data: 'some2' },
    { id: 4, data: 'some4' },
    { id: 6, data: 'some6' }
];

var res = merge(first, second, third);

console.info(res); /* =>

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "first"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "second",
    "filed": "foo2",
    "data": "some2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "third",
    "field": "foo3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "field": "foo4",
    "data": "some4"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "data": "some6"
  },
  length: 5
]
*/
```

Comment: Ха-ха-ха, все набежали. :)

Comment: Ну всплыл вопрос, я ответил, наверное для этого и делают поднятие.

Answer (score 2):

Если объединение идет по свойству `id`, то можно использовать следующий код:

```
function merge() {
    var hash = {}; // временный хэш объектов по свойству id
    for (var l = 0; l < arguments.length; l++) {
        var arr = arguments[l];
        if (!arr.length) continue;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var el = arr[i];
            if (!('id' in el)) continue;
            var id = el.id;
            if (!hash[id]) hash[id] = {};
            for (var key in el) {
                if (el.hasOwnProperty(key))
                    hash[id][key] = el[key];
            }
        }
    }
    var result = [];
    for (var id in hash) {
        if (hash.hasOwnProperty(id)) result.push(hash[id]);
    }
    return result;
}

var result = merge(first, second, third);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы планируете работать с коллекциями, объединять их, сортировать и производить прочие подобные операции, то я бы порекомендовал вам использовать для этого специальную библиотеку: [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) или [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Для выполнения запросов удобно работать с [LINQ.js](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/).

```
// Приводим массивы к удобному виду — словарю "индентификатор-значение"
var names  = Enumerable.From(first) .ToObject("$.id", "$.name");
var fields = Enumerable.From(second).ToObject("$.id", "$.field");
var datas  = Enumerable.From(third) .ToObject("$.id", "$.data");

// Получаем общий список ключей — объединение списков ключей из трёх словарей выше
var keys = Enumerable.From(Object.keys(names))
                    .Union(Object.keys(fields))
                    .Union(Object.keys(datas));

// Объединяем в общее перечисление
var joined = keys.Select(function (id) {
    return {
        id:    id,
        name:  names[id],
        field: fields[id],
        data:  datas[id]
    };
});

// Преобразуем перечисление к стандартному массиву
console.log(joined.ToArray());
```

```js
var first = [
    { id: 1, name: 'first' },
    { id: 2, name: 'second' },
    { id: 3, name: 'third' }
];

var second = [
    { id: 2, filed: 'foo2' },
    { id: 3, field: 'foo3' },
    { id: 4, field: 'foo4' }
];

var third = [
    { id: 2, data: 'some2' },
    { id: 4, data: 'some4' },
    { id: 6, data: 'some6' }
];

var names = Enumerable.From(first).ToObject("$.id", "$.name");
var fields = Enumerable.From(second).ToObject("$.id", "$.field");
var datas = Enumerable.From(third).ToObject("$.id", "$.data");

var keys = Enumerable.From(Object.keys(names))
    .Union(Object.keys(fields))
    .Union(Object.keys(datas));
var joined = keys.Select(function (id) {
    return {
        id: id,
        name: names[id],
        field: fields[id],
        data: datas[id]
    };
});

document.write(joined.ToJSON());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const mergeByProperty = (arrays, property = "id") => {
  const arr = arrays.flatMap((item) => item); //делаем из всех массивов - один

  const obj = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return { // делаем из массива - объект, чтобы повторения перезаписывались
      ...acc,
      [item[property]]: { ...acc[item[property]], ...item }
    };
  }, {});

  return Object.values(obj); //обратно преобразуем из объекта в массив
};

const first = [
  { id: 1, name: "first" },
  { id: 2, name: "second" },
  { id: 3, name: "third" }
];
const second = [
  { id: 2, filed: "foo2" },
  { id: 3, field: "foo3" },
  { id: 4, field: "foo4" }
];
const third = [
  { id: 2, data: "some2" },
  { id: 4, data: "some4" },
  { id: 6, data: "some6" }
];

const result = mergeByProperty([first, second, third]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
function smartMerge(mainProp, arrays) {
/*
  Более универсальная версия, но требуется оптимизация
  mainProp - общее свойство для всех элементов, всех массивов: число
  arrays = массив массивов ( простите за тавтологию )
*/
  var mergedArray = []; // конечный массив

  for(var arrayIndex in arrays) {
    var array = arrays[arrayIndex];

    for( var elementIndex in array) {
      var element = array[elementIndex];
      if (!mergedArray[element[mainProp]]) mergedArray[element[mainProp]]={};

      for( var prop in element) {
        mergedArray[element[mainProp]][prop] = element[prop];
      }

    }

  } 
  return mergedArray.filter(function (el) { return el;}); 
}

// используем
var arr = smartMerge('id', [first, second, third]);
```

[Живой пример( ответ в консоли )](http://jsbin.com/cotukinibo)

Answer (score 0):

Все можно сделать намного легче с помощью concat

```
var result = first.concat(second, third);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [...first, ...second, ...third];
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]